# Grant Uri permission to another activity

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to get image from device gallery and then show it in another activity.
Code in my activity:

```
private void startGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_OPEN_GALLERY)
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_OPEN_GALLERY &&  resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData()
        // here I save image uri to pass to another activity
    }
}
```

When I try to open uri in another activity I get `SecurityException`. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) says permission for received uri lasts until the activity that receives them is finished. So when my activity is finished I have no permission to read file.

Is there some way to prolongate uri permission to allow other activities open file by this uri? Or only way is to copy image to local app storage?

**UPD:** My goal is saving received uri in local db and allowing other activities and services read this file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there some way to prolongate uri permission to allow other activities open file by this uri?

Yes. [Include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` when you pass the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) from the first activity to the second activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Something.class).setData(uri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION));
```

Comment: Sorry. My  question is not clear enough. My goal is saving received uri in local db and allowing other activities and services read this file. Updated answer

Comment: @nnesterov: "My goal is saving received uri in local db" -- that will not work. If you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+, you can try to use `takePersistableUriPermission()`, and if that works, you can have long-term access to the content identified by the `Uri`. Otherwise, you need to make a local copy of the content. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Durable) for a demonstration of doing this.

Comment: @CommonsWare and if i need to prolongate uri permission to previous activity in backstack?

Comment: @Xan: `takePersistableUriPermission()` would cover that. Otherwise... to be honest, I am uncertain. If you happened to have used `startActivityForResult()`, you could try `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent` that you supply to `setResult()` and see if that works. This sort of scenario is one of the reasons why Google is steering developers towards having fewer activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION inside setResult Intent fail. try with takePersistableUriPermission

Comment: thanks, this approach works! i was receiving one or many files (`ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`) and I was able to keep permissions for all of those. I used a shortcut though, I simply repurposed the intent that I received using `setClass(applicationContext, TargetActivity.class)`. here's [an illustration](https://i.imgur.com/tErJRay.png)