# Pass Uri through from ACTION_GET_CONTENT through activity to service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a simple app that allows a user to upload data to my service. The user specifies one or more files by a initiating an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, or by receiving a `ACTION_SEND`. The Uri(s) from `getParcleableExtra` or `getParcleableArrayListExtra` are added to an array in UploadActivity, where the get/capture/send intents are received. Some of the Uris are opened with `ContentResolver.openInputStream(Uri)`, or various Cursors to get metadata. This succeeds without any errors. When the user wants to upload the files, the Uris are added to a intent that starts UploadService with `putParcleableArrayListExtra`. Then `startService` and `finish()` are called, closing the activity. UploadService is a `IntentService` which uploads the files over HTTP. All Uris are opened with Cursors querying their size for the progress bar. They are then, in serial, opened with `openInputStream` again, then uploaded to the server.

This works perfectly with only 1 Uri. If I have more than 1 Uri, `openInputStream` throws a SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aempty.txt from pid=6062, uid=10300 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1111)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:948)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:668)
        at tk.mii8303.yumeko.YetAnotherURI$OtherURI.Open(YetAnotherURI.java:73)
        at tk.mii8303.yumeko.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:119)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I don't see why I should need `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` if I already have called the same method on the file earlier in my app and had it succeed.
I have tried calling

```
takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
grantUriPermission("tk.mii8303.yumeko.UploadService", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

on each Uri before putting them in the intent to no avail.

How do I pass Uris and their permissions to my service?

Comment: Try this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898516/grant-uri-permission-to-another-activity

Comment: I think I tried that, though I ended up doing this the less-correct-but-works way of just starting a thread and doing the upload there.